# ServiceReferences.ClientConfig Missing - WCF with Silverlight on Azure

Tags: wcf, silverlight, azure

I have a fairly simple WCF service running in Azure. In a separate Azure deployment, I have a Silverlight application that needs to access the WCF service.

I have created the service as a Silverlight-enabled WCF Service and I have been able to use the "Add Service Reference" to get the access to the object. However, when I create the client, I get the below message.

> Cannot find 'ServiceReferences.ClientConfig' in the .xap application package. This file is used to configure client proxies for web services, and allows the application to locate the services it needs. Either include this file in the application package, or modify your code to use a client proxy constructor that specifies the service address and binding explicitly. Please see inner exception for details.

Everywhere I look on the internet, they tell me to simply include the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig but I am unable to find this ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file anywhere, in either my WCF Service project or my Silverlight project so I am unable to add it to my XAP. I tried specifying the endpoint URL using the specific constructor, but I got the same error.

So ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is missing. 
What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after a little bit of messing around. When I right clicked the service reference and updated it, the file automatically appeared in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would look in the actual project folder.  Maybe your settings in Visual Studio are hiding the file.  If it really doesn't exist, you can just create it.  Take a look at:

http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2010/01/27/creating-and-using-silverlight-app-settings-webconfig-configuration-applicatioin-settings-to-change-wcf-service-address-after-deployment-servicereferencesclientconfig-servicereferences-clientconfig/

You can also check this out for alternatives to that file, maybe you can use this instead if you like:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2009/02/23/silverlight-servicereferences-clientconfig-alternatives.aspx

Comment: Hey Tom. The file is not in the project folders. I've also used the svcutil.exe to generate the files, from which I get a .cs and a .config file but neither of these work either. I'm still experimenting with the alternatives but at a glance they don't seem like the "right" way to do it.